# How to run android2.2 google maps application in android 2.3.4 device

Tags: android

I am working on android2.3.4 version.
i would like to install my previous application into the 2.3.4 version device .
when iam installing iam getting the error that is
 Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY

can you please explian me regarding this and do the needfull to me

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your 2.3.4 device does not have Google Maps, based on that error message.